# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined, react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Instale `select2` en react:

```
npm install react-select2 select2 --save
```

Todo salio bien, pero cuando lo puse en practica me sale el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined

**Importe:**

```
import Select2 from 'react-select2-wrapper';
```

Luego mas abajo en el render:

```
<Select2
  data={[
    { text: 'bug', id: 1 },
    { text: 'feature', id: 2 },
    { text: 'documents', id: 3 },
    { text: 'discussion', id: 4 },
  ]}
  options={{
    placeholder: 'search by tags',
  }}
/>
```

Ya intente agregando:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Tanto en el archivo en que trabajo, como en la libreria de `select2`, pero el error persiste.

Comment: Puedes intentarlo de la siguiente forma.
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: Personalmente, probaría a usar otra librería, ya que `react-select2` no ha sido actualizada en [hace ya más de tres años](https://github.com/luqin/react-select2/releases), así que puede ser un error de la misma.

Comment: @AlterLagos, precisamente lo cambie y ahora estoy utilizando [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)